# Failed Prop Type in Gatsby Image

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-image

I wanted to inquire about something. I am trying to display staff images, bio, etc.

My query is like so:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    allContentfulStaff {
      edges {
        node {
          staffBio {
            staffBio
          }
          staffImages {
            id
            gatsbyImageData
            description
          }
          staffOneLine
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

My map function is like so:

```
return (
  <>
    <h1>Our Rockin' Staff</h1>
    {data.allContentfulStaff.edges.map((node, index) => {
      console.log(data.allContentfulStaff);
      return (
        <div>
          <GatsbyImage
            key={``}
            image={node.gatsbyImageData}
            alt={node.description}
          />

          {node.staffOneLine}
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </>
);
```

I receive the data from
`{node.staffOneLine }`, but nothing for the images.
When I console log `{data.allContentfulStaff}`, I see an array of images that I will attach.

However, I am getting an error which I will also attach… but none of my other queries / functions where I am grabbing images in the same manner are giving me this error and they look relatively similar. I also did not need the image prop in my components as I am using
`<GatsbyImage />`

[image: Error]

[image: Console Log]

[image: Console]

Curious if you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorted! Had to 
 ```
<GatsbyImage
   image={ item.node.staffImages[0].gatsbyImageData }
   alt={ 'staff image' } />```

Comment: You also need to call `getImage()` to process the image, not sure if you already have it not. `const image = getImage(item.node.staffImages[0].gatsbyImageData)`

Comment: `getImage()` is a optional helper function. It's not mandatory since it only shorten the property nesting and its usage relies on the approach. Moreover, if you use it, it should be something like: `const image = getImage(item.node.staffImages[0])` and I guess it won't work since the query lacks of sharps nodes

Answer (score 1):

`node` is an array/set of images as `staffImages` (of 1 position only) is, so you'll need to add directly to each position like:

```
<GatsbyImage image={item.node.staffImages[0].gatsbyImageData} alt={ 'staff image' } />
```

You are looping the data correctly as you pointed out with the `console.log()` but as you can see there, and because your data structure, `staffImages` is an array of one position (always) that holds the `gatsbyImageData` so you need to access directly to that position.

The `getImage()` function discussed in comments is completely optional and it won't change the fact that an image is showing/not showing at all. As you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#gatsbyimage):

> ```
> import { getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
>
> const image = getImage(data.avatar)
>
> // This is the same as:
>
> const image = data?.avatar?.childImageSharp?.gatsbyImageData
> ```